# Extract specific value within cell (RegEx Pattern)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

maybe someone of you can help me or maybe point me in the right direction how to solve this problem in excel.

I have a sheet with cells containing mixed values like:

texxtext W.1234.56 text

text text U.3853.23

P.3853.34 texttext

I just need the specific ArticleNumber (X.XXXX.XX) in between. Like this RegEx Pattern
([A-Za-z].\d\d\d\d.\d\d)

Is there a way to achieve this with Formular Functions?

Thanks in advance!

[A-Za-z].\d\d\d\d.\d\d

Comment: If your text is free from dots then you can use mid() and find(). So you start the mid() where you find() the dot minus 1 then length 9. But this will fail if there are dots in the article description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PY()**:

If applicable, you can use the `PY()` function for this:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=PY(
    xl("A1:A3").replace(r'.*\b([A-Za-z]\.\d{4}\.\d{2})\b.*', r'\1', regex=True)[0].values
)
```

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>At time of writing `PY()` is only available within the beta-channel of a ms365 subscription.</sub>

---

**SEARCH()**:

Otherwise, try something more simple first to see if it would be sufficient to use wildcard in a regular `SEARCH()` pattern:

```
=MID(A1:A3,SEARCH("?.????.??",A1:A3),9)
```

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>With this method I assume there is no, or a very slim, chance that there are other substring in your text that follow that exact pattern.</sub>

---

**FILTERXML()**:

Another, more intricate way would be to use `FILTERXML()`. That way you can utilize xpath-patterns that can check for the pattern at hand:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=9][concat(substring(., 2, 1),substring(.,7,1))='..'][translate(substring(.,1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][concat(substring(.,2,4),substring(.,8))*0=0]")
```

Here the and-ing structure of predicates mean:

- `[string-length()=9]` - Check that a node is 9 characters long;
- `[concat(substring(., 2, 1),substring(.,7,1))='..']` - When we concatenate the 2nd and 7th character it equals '..';
- `[translate(substring(.,1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')='']` - If we translate the character at the 1st index from any (uppercase) alphachar to nothing it equals an empty string;
- `[concat(substring(.,2,4),substring(.,8))*0=0]` - If we concat the remaining characters and multiply this by zero it would equal zero.

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>Here I have assumed a space-delimited string to begin with. We use the spaces to split the text into nodes. This is not as straightforward nomore if punctuation comes into play.</sub>

<sup>‡‡</sup> <sub>More information on `FILTERXML()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much! The combination of MID and SEARCH allready did the Job!
And Thanks for the other detailed helpful variants too...looking forward for the PY feature in my case, too :)

Comment: You are welcome. Was a fun question to work on. Still, please be weary for possible false positives when using `SEARCH()` since it's not checking for the exact pattern.

Comment: If you say Regex, you say JvdV. Very nice solutions. Including the simplistic MID.

Answer (score 0):

Using mid() with find():

=mid(A1,find(".",A1,1)-1,9)

But this uses the first "." and relies on 9 characters being the target.

Answer (score 0):

### Match a Pattern Simplified

[image]

- This is far from the regex accuracy but might serve you well.

```
=LET(data,A2:A5,pattern,"?.????.??",not_found,"",
    s,SEARCH(pattern,data),
IF(ISNUMBER(s),MID(data,s,LEN(pattern)),not_found))
```

or, more of the same:

```
=LET(data,A2:A5,pattern,"?.????.??",not_found,"",
IFERROR(MID(data,SEARCH(pattern,data),LEN(pattern)),not_found))
```